Parallel string recognizion using Scanner and Thread in Java not working
For a personal project I am working on a way to recognize a String through a JOptionPane. Now my goal is to also have it recognized when I put it in the console as well and then close the JOptionPane. For achieving this I was trying to implement a Thread which was supposed to work parallel. So when the JOptionPane would open also the console should be able to get commands and react to them using a Scanner. However it doesn't work at all. The Thread is not working parallel to the program but it seems it isn't reacting.
It doesn't matter if I put the Scanner for the console commands into the Thread or the JOptionPane itself. Also the order of what I call first (either the Thread or the Scanner) doesn't matter at all. The result is always the same that never the JOptionPane is showing but instead the program only waits for the input into the console. Only after that the JOptionPane will show up but all input there is ignored and overwritten by the former input into the console.
In the meantime I tried to implement several different attempts on how to solve this but none of them works. I feel like I am missing something essential here and since I don't have anyone to ask I hope you can help me instead. Since I am out of ideas I need the help of someone who has more experience then I do. Please help me how to fix this.
Here are the code examples I have tried so far:
First try:

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NameConsole extends Thread {
    
    public String answer = "";
    
    public void run(){
        answer = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        null,
                        "Please chose the reference. \n",
                        "choice of name",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        null,
                        "");
     }

}


public class SelectName {
    public static String setManualname(LinkedHashMap<Character,LinkedHashMap<String,Namer>> namesList) {
        
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {

            NameConsole nameconsole = new NameConsole();
            String name = "";
            
            while (sc.nextLine().equals("")) {
                nameconsole.run();
            
                if (!nameconsole.answer.equals(""))
                    name = nameconsole.answer;
                else if (sc.nextLine() != null)
                    name = sc.nextLine();
            }

        if (name == null || name.equals("") || name.equals("x")) {
            System.out.println("[ATTENTION] - a random reference will be loaded from the database.");
            return "";
        } else if (name.equals("auto") && name.length() > 2) {
            return "auto";
        } else if (name.contains("x_") && name.length() > 2) {
            deleteName(namesList, name.substring(2, name.length()), true); //this method excludes a name from the database
            return setManualname(namesList);
        } else if (name.contains("delete_") && name.length() > 7) {
            NameIndexer.deleteAllPictures(name.substring(7, name.length()));  //this method deletes a name from the database and also all related data from the harddrive
            System.out.println("Please chose a new reference: ");
            return setManualname(namesList);
        } else if (name.equals("all_names")) {  //shows all names currently in the database
            OperationsPrinter.printNamesList(namesList);
            System.out.println("All names displayed. Please chose a reference now: ");
            return setManualname(namesList);
        } else if (namesList.get(name.charAt(0)) == null || (!namesList.get(name.charAt(0)).containsKey(name) && !name.equals(""))) {
            System.out.println("ERROR - the chosen reference is not in the database. Please select another reference or type \"x\" to abort. To receive a list of all references in the database, please enter \"all_names\" into the console.");
            return setManualname(namesList);
        } else
            return null;
    }
}

Second try:
package engine.managers.collectors.identifier.nameconsole;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class NameConsole extends Thread {
    
    public String answer = "";
    
    public void run(){
        answer = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        null,
                        "Please chose the reference. \n",
                        "choice of name",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        null,
                        "");
     }

}


public class SelectName {
    public static String setManualname() {
        
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            String name = sc.nextLine();
            
            NameConsole nameconsole = new NameConsole();
            nameconsole.run();
            
            while (name.equals("")) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            
                if (!nameconsole.answer.equals(""))
                    name = nameconsole.answer;
                else if (name != null)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}

Third try:
package engine.managers.collectors.identifier.nameconsole;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NameConsole extends Thread {
    
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    public String answer = "";
    
    public void run(){
        answer = sc.nextLine();
     }

}


public class SelectName {
    public static String setManualname() {
        
        String name = "";
        String panelline = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                        null,
                        "Please chose the reference. \n",
                        "choice of name",
                        JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE,
                        null,
                        null,
                        "");
        
        NameConsole nameconsole = new NameConsole();
        nameconsole.run();
        
        while (name.equals("")) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        
            if (panelline != null)
                name = panelline;
            else if (!nameconsole.answer.equals(""))
                name = nameconsole.answer;
        }
    }
}


Please elaborate on what you expect to happen. Reading from the terminal is a blocking operation. And you never want to block the swing Event Dispatch Thread. But I really can't even tell what you're trying to do.

The background for the issue is that I am trying to load a name from a database that is loaded into the program. This is achieved by the JOptionPane.
However I don't want the JOptionPane to be able to access deeper options of the program. Only the console is supposed to do that. For that I want both to run simultaneously. So basically the console is supposed to load a name but also access program options while the JOptionPane is supposed to only be able to load a name.

The code given here is only the part concerning the part of my program which is making the issue. So the JOptionPane and the Thread.

None of these setManualname return a value, so they won't even compile. Both JOptionPane.showInputDialog and Scanner.nextLine will block, so you can't call either one before starting a thread you want to run concurrently. Setting a public field in one thread and trying to read it from another is not thread safe and will not work reliably. Is the idea that you want to prompt both in the GUI and on the command line, and use whichever one the user answers into first? Unfortunately, there's no way to close the input dialog once it is showing. What should it do once they type a name?

Both JOptionPane.showInputDialog and Scanner.nextLine will block, so you can't call either one before starting a thread you want to run concurrently. Setting a public field in one thread and trying to read it from another is not thread safe and will not work reliably.
Here's a version that I think does what you want. It works by running both the console prompt and the GUI prompt in separate threads by way of CompletableFuture. Then, the main thread waits for the first one that completes with a value.
Note that this implementation relies on shutting down the common thread pool and exiting the program after the first response, because there's no way to cancel or interrupt the blocking Scanner.nextLine call. This might not be suitable in the context of a larger program. There are solutions to this covered in other Stack Overflow answers (example), but they're more complex than using Scanner.
A key feature of this implementation is that it doesn't rely on mutable state shared between threads.
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool;

public class SelectName {
    private static String guiPrompt() {
        return JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                null,
                "Please chose the reference. \n",
                "choice of name",
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }

    private static String consolePrompt(Scanner sc) {
        var answer = "";
        while (answer.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print("Please chose the reference: ");
            answer = sc.nextLine();
        }
        return answer;
    }

    public static String promptForName(Scanner sc) {
        return (String) CompletableFuture.anyOf(
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(SelectName::guiPrompt),
                CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> consolePrompt(sc))
        ).join();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            System.out.println("\nUser entered: " + promptForName(sc));
            ForkJoinPool.commonPool().shutdownNow();
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}


This already displays both dialoges so it is a massive improvement. However the program is not proceeding once I have inserted an input in either the console or the JOptionPane. So if I put an input anywhere the program is still blocked instead of continuing. The point is for the program to continue with the input regardless wheather it came from the console or the JOptionPane. So we are half way through now.

In my code, the program does continue: it prints the value entered and then exits. I’m not really sure what your program needs to do next.

In my program the name that is supposed to be put in by the user with this method is to be used in the next step to load a bunch of data and pictures which are related to that same name. So it must not stop after having the name given by eiter the JOptionPane or the console but continue with that name.

If it helps, I can give more example of that code which I've left out in order to focus on the problem itself.

Maybe, but I probably won’t be able to write the data loading part of it without having the source of the data available. I think you would just need to replace the System.out.println part of the code with whatever else you need to do with the entered value.

I edited the first example of my attempts to show you what is supposed to happen after chosing a reference and what the method is supposed to return.
I hope this will help at least on an abstract level (Namer is a class I wrote specifically to collect all data that are referenced to one name, including a List and the name itself).

You don’t need to create any threads for this, because Java will already create an additional thread:  the AWT event dispatch thread.  Only programs which invoke AWT or Swing methods will have this thread created.
It appears one of your challenges is how to share data between the threads.  My advice would be:  don’t try.  The best way to address multi-threading challenges is to avoid them in the first place, as much as possible.
Instead of sharing data, create a separate class which performs the work.  You wrote:

The background for the issue is that I am trying to load a name from a database that is loaded into the program. This is achieved by the JOptionPane. However I don't want the JOptionPane to be able to access deeper options of the program. Only the console is supposed to do that.

So, create a separate class for doing that work:
class NameLookup {
    Object readNameFor(String name) {
        /* Database logic goes here */
    }

    Object readFullDataFor(String name) {
        /* Database logic goes here */
    }
}

Now your main program can simply call those methods:
private static void readFromDialog(NameLookup nameLookup) {
    while (true) {
        String answer = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                    null,
                    "Please chose the reference.",
                    "Choice of name",
                    JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
        if (answer == null) {
            // User canceled.
            break;
        }

        Object data = nameLookup.readNameFor(answer);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
            "Data for '" + answer + "' is " + data);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    NameLookup nameLookup = new NameLookup();

    // Run Swing code in AWT event dispatch thread.
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> readFromDialog(nameLookup));

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
        String name = sc.nextLine();

        Object data = nameLookup.readFullDataFor(name);

        System.out.println(
            "Full data for '" + name + "' is " + data);
    }
}


As I understand your example it asks for both the console and the JOptionPane to be given an input. My issue is that I want my program to only use one of this 2 inputs to proceed. Ideally both should reference the same value "name" and as soon as one of them receives an input, the program should continue without waiting for the other input.

I’m afraid what you want is not possible.  There is no way to interrupt a command line prompt.  The best you could possibly do is wait for that command line input, then display a message on the terminal along the lines of “Sorry, user has already provided input in a dialog.”  Is there a reason you want to do something as unusual as mixing terminal input and GUI input?  There is a reason no application tries to do such a thing.  It’s not a good design, as it’s highly confusing to end users.  You’d be better off with two GUI prompts.

So there is no way to just check if there is an input in the console and in case there is just close the JOptionPane? Or when I make an input into the JOptionPane just make the system insert it into the console?

My idea behind it was to have a way that is only available for admins or while debugging the program for inserting not only databank commands into the console but also access program options while with the JOptionPane only having access to the normal databank.

“So there is no way to just check if there is an input in the console…?”  Correct.  There is no way to do that.  The console does its own buffering and editing of input.  It is not under the direct control of programs.  Indeed, that is one reason to create a GUI.  You probably will need to design something a little more complicated than just showing JOptionPanes.  Perhaps a window with an “Enter admin command” button that displays its own separate prompt.
